# How to set custom colors in rubymine for matching strings

Tags: ruby, ide, rubymine

I'm looking for a way to change the color of specific text in the Rubymine IDE. 
Specifically I'd like to change the color of **'binding.pry'** since its easy to forget when its left in the code.

I've looked in the Settings > IDE Settings > Colors & Fonts section, but can't find anything to match a custom string.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was by finding usage using `Alt+F7`
I made a macro for that which would search for the occurrence of `binding.pry`